# ¿Como obtener la etiqueta numero un o de un archivo xml en c#?

Tags: c#, xml

Lo que quiero es obtener los hijos de mi etiqueta vídeos, que en este caso seria Matemática, pero cuando ejecuto mi código c# me obtiene los hijos de mi etiqueta Matemática, lo que viene siendo Tema1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Videos>
  <Matematica>Tema1</Matematica>
</Videos>
```

Codigo C#

```
XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
            XmlNodeList xmlnode;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(directorio + "XML\\videos.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            xmldoc.Load(fs);
            xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Videos").Item(0).ChildNodes;

            for (int i=0;i<=xmlnode.Item(0).ChildNodes.Count;i++)
            {
                listado.Add(xmlnode.Item(i).InnerText);

            }

            return listado;
```

Comment: A ver si entendi, quieres el nombre del tag o el texto del tag matematica?

Comment: @Einer el Nombre del Tag y ya despues con ese nombre saco su valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InnerText` te retorna el texto del nodo, en este caso, el texto del nodo `Matematica`. Si lo que quieres es obtener el nombre del nodo, entonces utiliza la propiedad `Name`:

```
//...
for (int i=0;i<=xmlnode.Item(0).ChildNodes.Count;i++){
   listado.Add(xmlnode.Item(i).Name);
}
//...
```